# Nginx http to https redirect not working for some clients

Tags: nginx

I have configured nginx to redirect http to https for my site. Here is my configuration block:

```
    server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name example.com www.example.com; 
    return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;
    # ......
    fastcgi_param   HTTPS               on;
    fastcgi_param   HTTP_SCHEME         https;

    root /var/www/example;
    index index.php index index.html index.htm;

    server_name www.example.com example.com;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
gzip on;
gzip_disable "msie6";

gzip_comp_level 6;
gzip_min_length 1100;
gzip_buffers 16 8k;
gzip_proxied any;
gzip_types
    text/plain
    text/css
    text/js
    text/xml
    text/javascript
    application/javascript
    application/x-javascript
    application/json
    application/xml
    application/rss+xml
    image/svg+xml;
    gzip_vary on;

    location ~*  \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|cur|js)$ {
        expires 7d;
    }
}
```

Http does not redirect to https for some clients and it takes long time with no response from server.But it redirects for some others! For example it does not work for my desktop browsers but redirects fine when accessed by my mobile browser.

This can be traced in nginx logs where there are 499 error codes for those than do not redirect and there are 301 codes for those that redirect.

Of course everything is fine on every browser when accessed directly from https.

Comment: 499 - means client closes the connection while nginx is processing the request. Check using dev. tools on client side.

Comment: I know 499 is for nginx logs only. I said clients say no response from server. sever returns nothing.